# Jelastic domain mapping issue

Tags: java, tomcat, dns, jelastic

I have deployed my java web application on JELASTIC.com  ,and everything went fine .

Now I want to map my domain to jelastic server where my app is running .
I referred doc and added CNAMe and mapped my domain in jelastic environment. 
When I goto my url(mydomain) I see tomcat home page (as in image) ..

When I type mysite/myprojectname  then I can see my application running on browser  ,instead I want my application to be mapped on mysite click instead of tomcat home page .

May be its small thing but I cant able to figure it out at this point . Can some one help me out .

I tried  the following doc

Click on config button for Tomcat, navigate to server.xml file (server directory) and set the configuration for host multiple domains (add Host tags for each domain you want to bind).

```
       <Host name="external.domain.tld" appBase="webapps/context_name" autoDeploy="true">
<Alias>external.domain.tld</Alias>
<Context path="" docBase="${catalina.base}/webapps/context_name"/>
</Host>
```

[image: site mapping show soemthing like this]

Edit:-
Yet I dont have public IP , I am trying jelastic trail plan .

Answer (score 1):

Your configuration looks good. But seems that you haven't restarted Tomcat after its configuring.
Also you can find example how to configure the domain name on Tomcat in the jelastic docs - http://docs.jelastic.com/multiple-domains2

Comment: Thanks @Aless ..I have restarted ,but no luck!!..tried many times by refering different docs ..

Comment: Could you please provide me with your domain name? I would like to look at the problem in real time.

Comment: Hello, @ULLAS K! Have you fixed that issue?

Comment: Hi @Aless, thanks for your concern ,  its all fine now... I have restarted and cleared cookies then its working fine